# PlainOAuth 401 Error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, twitter, oauth

I'm making an iPhone program that can post to Twitter.  I've downloaded Januus' PlainOAuth project, and I'm incorporating code into my own project. PlainOAuth is working fine, but my own project generates the following in the console when I post:

2010-10-18 21:53:09.990 TwitterTableView[18860:207] Status posted. HTTP result code: 401

One solution I found was to delete my app registration with Twitter and then make a new one.  I did this, and I'm still in the same situation.  I would be more specific about my code, but I would have to post the entire project to give details.

Comment: What are you sending to Twitter and what are you getting back from Twitter?